# How to convert Arraylist<ArrayList<objects>>to ArrayList<objects>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I will elaborate my question further.
I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<VehicleLoaded>>`, where VehicleLoaded is a class, with several arguments.
I want to have all those VehicleLoaded in one ArrayList, is there a way to obtain that?

e.g: I have this:

```
[
1:[VehicleLoaded100, VehicleLoaded200, VehicleLoaded300,VehicleLoaded400],
2:[VehicleLoaded104,VehicleLoaded205,VehicleLoaded301],
3:[VehicleLoaded650, VehicleLoaded890,VehicleLoaded103]
…
]
```

and I want to have this:

```
[VehicleLoaded100, VehicleLoaded200, VehicleLoaded300,VehicleLoaded400,
VehicleLoaded104,VehicleLoaded205,VehicleLoaded301,
VehicleLoaded650, VehicleLoaded890,VehicleLoaded103]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Good question. Duplicates might exist but you explained the question in very crisp manner. If anyone flags this question, I will fight.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with `Stream`s:

```
List<VehicleLoaded> list = 
    listOfLists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wow! I was about to write a naive answer but this one is way more elegant.

Comment: You should really have known that this was a duplicate.